# Creating a facebook likebox

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

A client of mine (a design studio) asked me to style the like-box social plugin on their site.
As far as I know this cannot be done now with the deprecation of "css" parameter on the fbml tag.

So the route I have to take is to recreate the like-box myself using the js SDK (or php SDK), but the problem is that I cannot find the users (and their photos) that like my page. I'm searching through the opengraph explorers parameters but i cannot find anything.

- Does anyone know which url I must follow in the graph api to get what I want?
- Do I have to have an access token for such an action? I noticed that the likebox plugin works event if you don't have a facebook account (It shows pictures).

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it's worth it. Users are used to the traditional facebook likebox anyway. I will not *install* another app just for you to show me a like plugin!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't recreate the like box on your own. The Facebook APIs will not return a list of users who like your object. This was done to stop people from getting user lists of likers and spamming them.

Currently, you can only query to find if a specific, authenticated user or which of their friends likes your object.

You could build something similar by populating your fake like box with images of recent posters. You would need to deal with filtering out duplicates, and the page posting as itself, but this should get you started: `/PAGE_ID/feed?fields=from.name,from.picture&limit=10`

You will need an `access_token` to get this data. I'd authenticate as an app to do it.